# Convert dijit.TitlePane to drop down button

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, arcgis-server

I have an app that I'm building using the javascript API and have created 3 titlepanes in the header that open up to reveal information (basemap gallery, legend, layers). It functions exactly how I want it to, now I would like to make it "look pretty" by giving each pane its own image, where when you click on the image, it opens the pane in the same way.

I have tried overriding the CSS however, that gives all the titlepanes the same image. It looks as though I'll need to convert the titlepanes to a togglebutton. Reading through some of the samples it looks like I'll need to add additional code beyond the html change. Is there a best way to go about this edit?

Here is an example of the html that creates the titlepane the "basemapGallery" div is the information inside the pane that I would like to make a drop down or any other type of button where I can control the image.

```
<div dojoType="dijit.TitlePane" title="Switch Basemap" closable="false" open="false" style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  style="width:275px; height:560px; overflow:auto;">
         <div id="basemapGallery"></div>
                </div>
  </div>
```

The header has a gray rectangular box that I would like to be an image, where you click on the image and it opens up the content located within the button.

**EDIT**
The end goal is for the buttons to have a similar look and feel to those in the header at:
http://localgovtemplates2.esri.com/ParkFinder/default.htm

Comment: Did you check my answer at GIS.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up finding some help via old posts that reference fx.toggler. Worked like a charm. Now its just about styling it the way I want, but the basic functionality is there.